# How to determine the sum of series?

Tags: real-analysis, summation

So, this is my first example.
How to determine the sum of series :

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}}{n}$.

Comment: Look at Taylor's series of $\ln(1+x).$

Comment: Or rewrite this with the harmonic series

Comment: In any case, please add some personal input to this question and to your future ones.

Comment: This is explained in any decent textbook in nauseating detail. Not many will be eager to add to the nausea.

Comment: Your first example of what? In what sense is it *your* example?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I first time I do such a task.  I have $\sum \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \cdot x^n$. So I know, that i must use differentiability function $f(x)= \sum \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^N (-x)^{n-1}\,dx=\int_0^1 \frac{1-(-x)^N}{1+x}\,dx$$

---

Alternatively, we can write

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac1n=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n+N}=\frac1N\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{1+n/N}$$

which is a Riemann Sum.